# Colours in Illustrator CC are not the same as in other software

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, pdf

I've got a problem with Adobe Illustrator CC. The fact is that I create a design just with black and red colour (#EC0000). But then, when I save this document in PDF or when I export it to JPEG, and open them with Adobe Reader and "Photos" software from Microsoft respectively, that red colour changes into a darker one. First I thought it was cause of the options I select when I save the document. But taking into account that when I open the PDF or the JPEG file with Illustrator CC, the red colour changes again to he brighter one, that made no sense for me... What could be the reason then?

Thank you.

Comment: Misconfigured color management. #EC0000 does not tell what red color you choose all it tells is that on device coordinates in this case it happens to be a shade of red, but any other device in universe will see it as a different color. So you use a color manager, misconfiguring the color manager will make things go wrong. But then you would need calibrated systems. This question is a duplicate it gets asked about evefy month or so.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I still don't understand. When you are talking about devices, you mean software? Cause I see different colours in the same device (my PC), but just different software.

Comment: No im talking of display devices. Color managed applications try to compensate for the monitors color difference. Obviously if it compensates it wrong you get wrong color 2 times.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your applications are colour profile aware, and others aren't.   Devices can have colour profiles, which some software reads and adjusts, due to.  Others don't care and just spew out what they think is right.